# on git push getting "remote: Internal Server Error ! [remote rejected] main -> main (Internal Server Error)"

Tags: git

everything is working fine when I use git, until a few moments ago I'm getting this error:

```
>git push
Enumerating objects: 21, done.
Counting objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 1.10 KiB | 187.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8), completed with 7 local objects.
remote: Internal Server Error
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (Internal Server Error)
```

I checked https://www.githubstatus.com/ and not sure what this means if it's an error on Github's end or my end?

Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 4):

Github is down, you can check the status here https://www.githubstatus.com/

It's a global issue

Comment: Thanks! also can check https://twitter.com/githubstatus